# wordpress site - using custom database and PHP

Tags: php, database, html, sql

I have finally finished coding a project with an HTML form for file upload, and a large PHP file that submits a 200 field CSV into my database. It first uploads to a staging table and then splits the data into smaller tables. This all works perfectly but I'm having problems with the next step: This is needed to run on a wordpress site that already exists. I have a database just for this project with tables for users, clients, staging, meters, etc. I need all of these tables in their own database because these users are separate from the WP users. I found a plugin that allows you to insert PHP into pages, but I need to know how to work with a custom database in WP, I've only ever worked with the actual database. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather than inserting PHP into pages, it would be safer to create your own theme, with template PHP files which perform the necessary operations.

Comment: Yes, I definitely realize it can be a security issue to insert the PHP, but this was just for a testable project so I wasn't as concerned with that aspect. I was more curious about how to integrate a custom db table with the existing theme

Comment: If you're inserting the PHP directly into the content it's not really a WordPress-specific question. You can just use mysqli_connect as in any PHP. If instead you'd like to do things a safer, more standard way, you'd perform the same function within theme templates - or perhaps in a plugin that you call using shortcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we do not know how the data should be represented on the 'front-end' (read WP install), it is hard to say.

- You could convert the existing database to use [custom tables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins).
- Create a small [REST](https://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=what%20is%20rest%20api&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XdjbWNLlPInc8Ae9wZCQBg)<sup>(1)</sup> [JSON/XML](https://www.mashery.com/blog/api-data-exchange-xml-vs-json)<sup>(1)</sup> [API](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api)<sup>(1)</sup> on the 'other' application. Then [code a WordPress plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) that shows the data from the API [with shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). 
  You can 'cache' this data with the use of the [transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). Or use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) to get the information asynchronous either via your application or some custom back-end code that uses the [WordPress AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).
- If the data isn't *that* complicated, you could try to 'convert' it into a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). This way your data is manageable with the standard WordPress admin.

I've tried to provide some ideas how to combine WordPress and 3rd party content. This list can probably a bit longer, but these would be the obvious ones. *If* you could give us a bit more insight to about what data your handling, that would make it tonnes easier to assess and give you an idea to handle it.

I've also added a few links to the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org). It contains all the necessary explanations and code examples you need.

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> Small Google Search</sup>
<sup><sup>(2)</sup> Third result on Google</sup>
<sup><sup>(3)</sup> First result on Google</sup>